# Yocto - rootfs size is smaller on target than in workdir

Tags: linux, root-filesystem, yocto

I use Yocto to build an image for my development board and I noticed that the same command `du -sh` showed smaller value when I checked it on the running system than in the yocto work directory. The difference is about 20%. Do you have any idea why? I thought that the rootfs on the target is exactly the same as the rootfs directory inside work directory in Yocto.

Comment: Which rootfs are you comparing it to? Those in `tmp/deploy/images`? Or the sum of those rootfs distributed under `tmp/work` or what else?

Comment: I'm comparing rootfs on the target with `build/tmp/work/<machine>/<image>/rootfs` directory.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that the rootfs on the target is exactly the same as the rootfs directory inside work directory in Yocto.

It's the same files, not the same file system.